# Opening a new activity on the click of a button in an Android Application

Tags: java, android, xml

Here is my problem. I created a button id: "fibo1" . This button belongs to the 'CList' Activity. On clicking the button I would like to open another Activity named ""Fibonacci"

XML of 'CList'

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fibo1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="sendMessage"
            android:text="Fibo" />
```

Java of CList

```
public class CList extends Activity {
    Button read1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list);


        read1 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.fibo1);
        read1.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick (View v){
                Intent intent = new Intent (CList.this,Fibonacci.class);
                startActivity (intent);
                finish();
            }
       });
    }
```

The Application crashes on opening the 'List' activity from the Main Activity. Log Cat gives the error `Fatal Exception :main`.
I have added both the Activities to the Android Manifest.
I'm just a beginner, so forgive me if my terminology is incorrect.

Here is the Log Cat

```
03-07 19:33:29.931: E/AndroidRuntime(19565): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

03-07 19:33:29.931: E/AndroidRuntime(19565): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.geek.cprogramspopular/com.geek.cprogramspopular.CList}: java.lang.NullPointerException

03-07 19:33:29.931: E/AndroidRuntime(19565):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)

03-07 19:33:29.931: E/AndroidRuntime(19565):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)

03-07 19:33:29.931: E/AndroidRuntime(19565):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)

03-07 19:33:29.931: E/AndroidRuntime(19565):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)

03-07 19:33:29.931: E/AndroidRuntime(19565):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

03-07 19:33:29.931: E/AndroidRuntime(19565):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

03-07 19:33:29.931: E/AndroidRuntime(19565):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)

03-07 19:33:29.931: E/AndroidRuntime(19565):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

03-07 19:33:29.931: E/AndroidRuntime(19565):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

03-07 19:33:29.931: E/AndroidRuntime(19565):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)

03-07 19:33:29.931: E/AndroidRuntime(19565):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)

03-07 19:33:29.931: E/AndroidRuntime(19565):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

03-07 19:33:29.931: E/AndroidRuntime(19565): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

03-07 19:33:29.931: E/AndroidRuntime(19565):    at com.geek.cprogramspopular.CList.onCreate(CList.java:23)

03-07 19:33:29.931: E/AndroidRuntime(19565):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5283)

03-07 19:33:29.931: E/AndroidRuntime(19565):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)

03-07 19:33:29.931: E/AndroidRuntime(19565):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)

03-07 19:33:29.931: E/AndroidRuntime(19565):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: post your full code and the error log

Comment: why are u calling finish() from your click handler?

Comment: You have sendMessage as click inside your xml layout. This method isn't inside your Activity. Remove the line: android:onClick="sendMessage" inside your xml. Not sure if that's the problem.

Comment: Post your **sendMessage** method

Comment: I've removed the line :android:onClick="sendMessage"
That has not solved the problem. @Francescoverheye

Comment: then post the code you are using

Comment: If you are getting NPE while opening CList (not while clicking the button), problem may be setting wrong layout to your CList activity. does list.xml have same content with the layout you've shared? read1 may be null and then you are getting NPE? try to debug it.

Comment: Have you registered second activity in manifest?

Comment: which line is number 23?

Comment: <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.geek.popular.CList"
         />
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.geek.popular.Fibonacci"
         /> 
I have added these lines to the manifest. @Tech Agent

Comment: When I run the application without the code:
 read1 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.fibo1);
        read1.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick (View v){
                Intent intent = new Intent (CList.this,Fibonacci.class);
                startActivity (intent);
                finish();

The application doesn't crash on opening the 'CList' activity.

Comment: Thankyou for the help everyone I managed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You just remove this line from your XML file and you need not to finish your activity in the Intent Calling...

```
android:onClick="sendMessage"
read1.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent (CList.this,Fibonacci.class);
            startActivity (intent);                
        }
   });
```

Comment: I tried this. The problem still persists. I think the problem is with the 'Clist' layout.. the changes made in it on Eclipse are not reflecting in the Application.

Answer (score 0):

use the following code -

```
public void sendMessage(View v) {

     Intent intent = new Intent(CList.this, Fibonacci.class);
     startAcitivty(intent);
}
```

after `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method, instead of this -

```
read1.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent (CList.this,Fibonacci.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
}
```

you may also remove `Button read1;` and `read1 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.fibo1);` after doing this.

Comment: That wasn't the problem. I managed to find a fix. Thanks anyway.